# Error in discord.py when i try to use a function

Tags: python, syntax-error, discord.py

When I try to run my bot, I get an error: `attributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'`  the code that it is originating in is  `@client.command() async def beg(ctx):`

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) recommends:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    pass

# or:

@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    pass

bot.add_command(test)
```

If you want a answer considering your specific issue, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).